How to Derive the Poisson Kernel in Higher Dimensions?
I am trying to derive the Poisson kernel $ P(x, y) $ in higher dimensions, specifically in $ \mathbb{R}^n $. I know that the result should be:
$$ P(x, y) = C_{n,a} \frac{y^{1-a}}{( |x|^2 + y^2 )^{\frac{n+1-a}{2}}} $$
where $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $, $ y > 0 $, $-1<a<1$ and $ C_{n,a} $ is a normalization constant depending on $ n $ and $ a $.
To start, I know that the Fourier transform of the Poisson kernel in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by:
$$ \hat{P}(\xi, y) = e^{-|\xi| y}, $$
where $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
I would like to understand the detailed steps to derive this kernel in the physical space, including:

The conditions required for the derivation.
The role of spherical coordinates and the set $ S^{n-1} = \{\omega \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid |\omega| = 1\} $.
The use of Bessel functions and their properties.
The evaluation of the integral involving the exponential function and Bessel function.

I am familiar with the basics of Fourier transforms and inverse Fourier transforms. Specifically, I want to derive the inverse Fourier transform of $ \hat{P}(\xi, y) = e^{-|\xi| y} $ to obtain the kernel in the physical space.
Could someone please provide a step-by-step derivation or guide me through the process? Any references to detailed derivations or notes would also be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

what is ${}{}a$?

Thanks for noticing, I forget to mention that $-1<a<1$. Edited now!
